# Pointer Functions in C: initialization of foo from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I'm working with C, and not allowed to use C++. Currently, I'm trying to implement some level of OOP in C. I'm currently working on trying to implement polymorphism and inheritance.

I've spent the majority of the day reading up on how my goals are possible through the use of function pointers. I am attempting to print the members variables of both structs as seen here:

RecordObject.h

```c
typedef struct SuperRecordObject 
{
    char *Id;
    char *date;
    char *cases;
    char *deaths;
    void (*ptrPrintRecord)(char *id, char *date, char *cases, char *deaths, char *names_fr, char *names_en);  
} SuperRecord;

typedef struct ChildRecordObject
{
    SuperRecord super;
    char *names_fr;
    char *names_en;
} ChildRecord;
```

I have defined the function `ptrPrintRecord` in this file:

RecordObject.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "RecordObject.h"
void ptrPrintRecord(char *id, char *date, char *cases, char *deaths, char *names_fr, char *names_en)
{
    //char *record;
    printf("     %s |   %s |            %s | %s |   %s |  %s\n", id, date, cases, deaths, names_fr, names_en);
    //return record;   
}
```

And I try to use the function in this file, as such:

DataLayer.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "RecordObject.h"
/* more code here */

void(*fun_ptr)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*) = &record.super.ptrPrintRecord; //
(*fun_ptr)(record.super.Id, record.super.date, record.super.cases, record.super.deaths, record.names_fr, record.names_en);

/* more code here */
```

However, when I compile (using GCC), I get this warning which causes a crash.

```
warning: initialization of 'void (*)(char *, char *, char *, char *, char *, char *)' from incompatible pointer type 'void (**)(char *, char *, char *, char *, char *, char *)' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   62 |        void(*fun_ptr)(char*,char*,char*,char*,char*,char*) = &record.super.ptrPrintRecord;
```

I've ran some other pointer functions in other files to mess around and test it, and the only thing I can think of as to what's going on here is it's maybe got something to do with how strings work in C?

Comment: It appears you are not showing the actual code. Error says `void*(*fun_ptr)` but you are showing `void(*fun_ptr)`.

Comment: Ah, I must of changed something without saving before posting. I've reran it and adjusted the error output now.

Comment: You don't initialize the function pointer in SuperRecord but then you use that uninitialized pointer to initialize fun_ptr.  But I don't understand the point of using fun_ptr when you could just use record.super.ptrPrintRecord directly (after initializing it of course)  For example, this works:  https://onlinegdb.com/B13IqSvFw

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I need to use function pointers because the plan is to implement a very basic form of inheiretance/polymorphism in C, which from what I stand is only possible by using pointer functions. As such, calling it directly isn't an option from what I understand at the moment

Comment: This is what I was imagining you would do: https://onlinegdb.com/Hyj1xIvYP

Comment: What do you think of this?  It still uses char* in the records so they don't take any space, but it allocates the memory so it has a destructor: https://onlinegdb.com/Hy5LMDvKw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extraneous `&` in your attempted function pointer assignment. The `ptrPrintRecord` member of your structure is *already* a function pointer of the correct type, so you don't need the `&` - which would give the **address** of that pointer.

Just use:

```c
void(*fun_ptr)(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*) = record.super.ptrPrintRecord; // No &
```

*As a side note, your use of `ptrPrintRecord` as that member (function pointer) **and also** as the name of an actual function (with the same 'signature') is likely to cause some issues, further down the road.*

---

Furthermore, you need to actually initialize that member (pointer) to a valid function address before copying it to something you then call (as also with the other  members of the structure). Here's a small `main` (using your other code) that works:

```c
int main()
{
    ChildRecord record;
    record.super.ptrPrintRecord = ptrPrintRecord; // See my note about the name clash!
    record.super.Id = "ID";
    record.super.date = "today";
    record.super.cases = "cases";
    record.super.deaths = "deaths";
    void(*fun_ptr)(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*) = record.super.ptrPrintRecord; //
    // To call the pointed-to function, we can just use the pointer name:
    fun_ptr(record.super.Id, record.super.date, record.super.cases, record.super.deaths, record.names_fr, record.names_en);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just added that, however, it still crashes. No compiler warning this time. However, if I comment out `(*fun_ptr)(record.super.Id, record.super.date, record.super.cases, record.super.deaths, record.names_fr, record.names_en);` it will run. Now I assume there must be an issue with the call to the function? I've tried calling the member fields and calling them manually else where and that works...

Comment: @ComradeSpaceMan Please ask a seperate question for that crash. And when you do please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For example, we need to see how `record` is defined and initialised.

Comment: @ComradeSpaceMan See edit - you need to initialize your 'record' members.

Comment: @AdrianMole `record.super.ptrPrintRecord = ptrPrintRecord;` I tried to initilize the function like you did (I do initilize the other members in another part, I am able to retrieve those so I know those work) but when I do this, I get an error saying 'identifier ptrPrintRecord' is undefined? I have my #includes set up properly, and I've changed nothing else from my original question...

Comment: You need to provide a function declaration for `ptrPrintRecord` that is visible in DataLayer.c. Add the following to your RecordObject.h file: `void ptrPrintRecord(char *id, char *date, char *cases, char *deaths, char *names_fr, char *names_en);`

Comment: Incidentally, one of the reasons we ask for sufficient code in questions is to avoid protracted discussions (like this) in follow-up comments. I don't mind, but some folks may be inclined to take umbrage.

Comment: @AdrianMole Ah, damn. Everything works now. Apologies, I will add more code next time, I figured I had everything figured out up to that point. To be frank, I was under the impression that I didn't need to declare `ptrPrintRecord` in that manner if I had the pointer function in the struct. So with what I had originally, with this line ` void (*ptrPrintRecord)(char *id, char *date, char *cases, char *deaths, char *names_fr, char *names_en);`, what exactly is this establishing? Simply reserving space for a pointer to point a function, but nothing more?

Comment: @ComradeSpaceMan Yep! The two different things called `ptrPrintRecord` are just that - two *different* things. Again, read my "side note" warning.

Comment: The line you added to your header file (that I suggested) is telling the compiler, when it processes other source files, that there is a function with the given name and signature *defined* elsewhere. The actual function address will be added to the built program by the linker, following successful compilation of all relevant source files.